# syntax error: `do^M' unexpected in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE=/abc/def
DEST=/xyz/ijk
FILE1=fun.c
FILE2=hello.c

if [ ! -d $DEST ]
then
   echo "Directory $DEST not found!"
   mkdir -p $DEST
fi

for FILE in $FILE1 $FILE2
do
   SRC=$BASE/$FILE
   TRG=$DEST/$FILE
   if [ -e $SRC ]
   then
      if [ -e $TRG ]
      then
          rm -f $TRG
      fi
      ln $SRC $TRG
      echo "Creating link for $SRC file..."
   else
      echo "File $SRC does not exists!"
   fi
done
```

I am getting

> link.sh[15]: syntax error: `do^M' unexpected

I ran tool `dos2unix` to remove all `^M` characters but still the same error is coming. I am running this script on ARM embedded target which is having only `/bin/sh` and no `bash`.

Comment: You need to remove the `^M` character.

Comment: I am not able to see any `^M` character. I checked using `set invlist` in vim editor and also running `dos2unix` on the script file.

Comment: What does `:set ff?` say?

Comment: @melpomene fileformat=unix

Comment: `sed 's/\r//g' link.sh > link.sh.new`  (you probably don't need the `g` modifier, but it won't do any harm)

Comment: `cat -A <file>` may be of some help too!

Comment: Are you editing the script on the target? If not, how do you transfer it thereon?